# Question about the while loop, should I use *or* or *and*?

Tags: python, while-loop

Why is it necessary to use **and** and vice versa in the while loop where **or** is appropriate in meaning?

Comment: What? Where? Could you give some example code?

Comment: If one is more appropriate than the other, don't use the other.

Comment: They do different things.  This is like asking "when should I add and when should I subtract?"  Nobody can answer other than explaining what those words mean.

Answer (score 1):

'and' is working only when every condition is satisfied
while 'or' is working when even one of conditions is true